# Remove y-tick labels on a dummbell plot to create space

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I got help on here to use the facet-wrap for my dumbbell plot but I want to create space for my graph. This is the current graph with facet_wrap. So I just want the y-ticks to appear once(i.e., on the left plots) that[image]

```
data10A <- structure(list(Session = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), conditon2 = structure(c(10L, 
4L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 
11L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 8L), .Label = c("CEN_LLL", "CTL_LLL", 
"IPS_LLL", "CEN_RRR", "CTL_RRR", "IPS_RRR", "CEN_RLR", "CTL_RLR", 
"IPS_RLR", "CEN_LRL", "CTL_LRL", "IPS_LRL"), class = "factor"), 
    Trial_type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Retention", "Transfer"), class = "factor"), 
    NormalizedJerk_102 = c(1270.168699, 2099.703957, 3259.268053, 
    1152.257445, 3810.890123, 4601.918336, 1792.371775, 1288.768888, 
    2699.08162, 1650.968794, 2018.457394, 6159.567785, 931.350429, 
    1053.84252, 1611.673955, 1034.363607, 5352.195367, 2499.83996, 
    1560.678962, 915.3845866, 1948.757464, 1341.815274, 2113.732859, 
    2051.140838), NormalizedJerk_104 = c(853.7034116, 924.8554548, 
    2268.966702, 675.7160839, 2442.874632, 1603.954653, 1010.111276, 
    794.1752256, 1313.813984, 1197.638788, 1039.577947, 3125.131019, 
    561.2311988, 767.7541159, 1019.744071, 769.6067294, 2232.404471, 
    1292.509181, 884.8343164, 663.0273865, 1230.369444, 717.8466364, 
    1536.027898, 1027.358586), key = c("Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dumbbell)
library(ggh4x)

data10A$key <- paste(data10A$Trial_type, data10A$Session, sep = "\n")
dumbbell::dumbbell(data10A, id = "conditon2", key = "key",
                   leg = "Test", 
                   column1 = "NormalizedJerk_102", 
                   column2 = "NormalizedJerk_104", 
                   delt = 1, lab1 = "Pre-test", lab2 = "Post-test", 
                   p_col1 = "black", p_col2 = "grey40", 
                   textsize = 4, segsize = 1.5, 
                   pointsize = 2.5, 
                   title = "Change in Normalized jerk from Pre- to Post-test")  + 
  facet_wrap( ~ key, scales="free", ncol=2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, color = "black"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBMK your desired result could not achieved by `facet_nested` alone. The issue is that with `scales="free"` you end up with a "duplicated" y-scale per facet. However, simply dropping `scales="free"` is not an option as in that case you end up with a plot showing the unused `condition2` categories in each facet.

Therefore one option to achieve your desired result would be to make separate plot for each `Trial_Type` and glue them together using e.g. `patchwork`. This will allow you to drop `scales="free"`. Additionally, to make use of `facet_nested(_wrap)` I dropped `dumbbell` and constructed the dumbbell chart from scratch using `geom_segment` and `geom_point` plus `geom_text` to add the labels for the differences.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
library(patchwork)
library(magrittr)

make_dumbbell <- function(x, max_x) {
  n_y <- length(unique(x$conditon2))
  
  x$conditon2 <- as.character(x$conditon2)
  
  ggplot(x, aes(y = conditon2, yend = conditon2)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = NormalizedJerk_102, xend = NormalizedJerk_104), size = 1.5, color = "gray80") +
    geom_point(aes(NormalizedJerk_102, color = "pre"), size = 2.5) +
    geom_point(aes(NormalizedJerk_104, color = "post"), size = 2.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::number(abs(NormalizedJerk_104 - NormalizedJerk_102), accuracy = .1)),
              x = max_x, hjust = 1, fontface = "bold"
    ) +
    annotate(geom = "text", label = "DIFF", y = n_y + 1, x = max_x, color = "red", fontface = "bold", hjust = 1) +
    scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(.6, 1.6))) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(pre = "black", post = "grey40"), labels = c(pre = "Pre-Test", post = "Post-Test")) +
    facet_nested_wrap(~ Trial_type + Session) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
      legend.position = "top",
      legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
      legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
      strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, color = "black")
    ) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, color = "Test")
}

max_x <- 1.25 * max(c(data10A$NormalizedJerk_102, data10A$NormalizedJerk_104))

data10A %>%
  split(.$Trial_type) %>%
  lapply(make_dumbbell, max_x = max_x) %>%
  wrap_plots(ncol = 1) + 
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") & 
  theme(
    legend.position = "top"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, once last thing - is there a way I can make the legend appear?

Comment: I just made an edit to add the legend.

Comment: I  your code exactly on my device by keeps appearing on the right, I dont know why

Comment: Aw. Sorry. I have made a change after I added the reprex but deleted the wrong line. I just fixed it. I has to be `theme(legend.position = "top")` at the end of the code not `legend.text = element_text(size = 12)`.